# How to make an image full screen on mobile devices but not in desktop?

Tags: html, css, layout, mobile, fullscreen

I put an image to inform that my site is under construction. It's a 800x600 image that maintain it's original size when you access in desktop. It's the only thing in the page.

I want to make it fit in the whole screen when people access it from cell phones. How?

```
<style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #6BC5C5; }
</style>
<title>Size is being moved to another server</title>
<div style="margin: 0; padding: 0; left: 0; top: 0; border: 0; position: absolute;">
<img src="movedatacenter.jpg" alt="Under Maintenance" width="595" height="1021" align="left"></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want to use is media queries.  Using a media query, you can enforce different CSS rules based on screen size.

For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    img#underconstruction {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding; 0;}
}
```

That will force an img with the id of underconstruction to go full width and height if the device screen is 600px or smaller.  600 is a good size because the newer iphones have a greater height than 480.

In addition, you'll need to force the view port to a 1:1 ratio on mobile devices with the following meta tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

Comment: yep, this is the best solution, +1

Comment: and what if my picture needs a vertical scroll, may I use height: *; instead of 100% ?

Comment: @EASI The device will scroll vertically if the image is too tall.  I don't know what height:* is.

Comment: it's the same as "height: auto" I have tested and it worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Set the style of the image with the following:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
max-width: 800px;
max-height: 600px;
```

This will expand the size of the image to the parent up to 800x600.
Make sure the parent element is also the width of the window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS media queries for this

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
/* 768px is usually the width of tablets in portrait orientation */
/* You can use any other size you see fit */

    img {width: 100%;}
}
```

This will apply the style information only when the width is under the given `max-width`.